# How to add Google Maps coordinates into ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, point

I have set the standard "World Imagery" as a basemap in ArcMap. Now I want to search for places from which I have the coordinates through Google Maps. Let's say I would like to display 51°38'27.1"N 6°33'53.9"E (51.639771, 6.566256) in ArcMap on my "World Imagery" basemap. I have been using the XY-Tool in ArcGIS and also tried to create a new point-shape class. However, whatever I do, it doesn't work. I checked the coordinate systems (GCS_WGS_1984), but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `6.566256, 51.639771`, i.e longitude, latitude.

GIS software generally uses X, Y coordinate references, so when you have latitude, longitude (Y, X) you need to reverse them

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: @alex then please accept the answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

An article [Adding Excel Lat Long Coordinates into ArcGIS](https://gisgeography.com/adding-excel-lat-long-coordinates-arcgis/) in **GISGeography** provides a detailed, quick and easy approach to solve your question.

1. Convert degrees/minutes/seconds to decimal degrees (***X field should equal longitude. The Y field should equal latitude***);
2. Ensure data frame is set to WGS 1984;
3. Add Excel table to ArcMap;
4. Display XY Data;
5. Save as feature class.